# How can I add these left and right arrows to my toolbar?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I would like to layout a "photo" view in my app like the following:

[image]

Any idea where can I find these arrows in the bottom and how to add them the same way ?

Also any idea on how to disable for example the left arrow when there's no previous item like in this picture:

[image]

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple UIView with background color black and alpha 0,8. Insert two custom UIButton with arrow images. You could do that in IB or prorgammaticly. Icons for arrows could be found in many free icon kits. Google for "free toolbar icon iPhone".